# Why don't Download Events and Download Goals match up in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I am using Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics to track events for downloads from my site. I am then using an event tracking Goal based on the "Download" category. The number of events in the "Download" category is ~2X the number of goals being tracked. Does this indicate an issue with either the events or the goal set up, or is this expected and why?
[image][image][image]

Comment: Note: The Regex for downloads is to capture an old method of firing events as well as the newer GTM method, so I am using the following to capture them all download|downloads|Download|Downloads

Comment: GA will track any goal conversion once per visit. It won't count repeat goal conversions per session. Hence, people could download multiple files (thereby triggering multiple download events, but only one goal conversion). Since there are considerably more unique events (which also appear only once per session) this doesn't seem to answer your question yet. Is the event cateogry subdivided into several event actions?

Comment: @SomewhereDave I didn't realize that! Yes there are multiple actions which explains it. Can you formulate your comment about events/goals into an answer?

Comment: I'd check the tag manager trigger to double check the number of times the action of the event is fired. Was that done?

Comment: @Prasad the trigger is set to "some link clicks" the other option is "all link clicks"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GA will track any goal conversion once per visit. It won't count repeat goal conversions per session. Hence, people could download multiple files (thereby triggering multiple download events, but only one goal conversion). If the event action is subdivided into several event actions and/or event labels, you will see more unique events than goal conversions. Use event action/label as a secondary dimension in the event reports to see if this holds true.

For exmaple:
Consider two events with

Event 1:
EC: Download
EA: FileA

Event 2:
EC: Download
EA: FileB

would result in one goal conversion for download, but two unqiue events.